# Cursor in a MDX expression?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mdx, ssas

I have a

```
TABLE A(
 Type INT,
 Value INT
)
```

Now I want to calculate the difference between the Value of each two subsequent lines of the same Type.

In SQL I'd use a Cursor and make the calculations myself. Is there a more efficient of doing this using a MDX expression (either with a script command or in a calculated member)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only going to work on an SQL server that integrates an MDX engine (not the 'classical' other way around). The only one I know where it might work is Oracle, is this your system?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but as the tags suggest, my system is SQL SERVER 2008. The solution was running the cursor on a job and inserting the values to a separate table used to feed Analysis Services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MDX is the answer. I'd `JOIN` the table to itself to create pairs of adjacent rows, and get the difference that way.